# Useless variable in BigInteger class, why?

Tags: java

I was browsing through the Java code today and I noticed something.

```
int[] m = mag;
int len = m.length;
int[] xm = xInt.mag;
if (len != xm.length)
    return false;
```

(This is in the `BigInteger` class, which can be found by unzipping `src.zip`. It's in the `equals` method.) Why is an entirely new variable `m` created when it is only used once? Why isn't the code just `int len = mag.length`? I saw this in another method also (`bitLength`), and again, `m` is only used once. Is there any advantage to doing this or is it just a mistake by the creators of this class?

Edit: as @usernametbd pointed out, it is used a bit later:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (xm[i] != m[i])
        return false;
```

But they still could have just used `mag`. Why would an entirely new variable be made?

In a different function (in the same class, `bitLength`), a new variable `m` is made and it's only used a single time.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Java source you're describing?

Comment: @templatetypedef It's in the Java source code itself. (rt.jar)

Comment: Similarly, the local variable `int m[]` is used in `java.math.BigInteger.bitLength()` just once.

Comment: @reprogrammer Yes, I said that in my post. (I saw this in another method also, and again, `m` is only used once.)

Comment: Decompilation is not 100% accurate; in particular, it often involves "reconstructing" high-level expressions from low-level instructions. It's possible `m` doesn't appear in the code really; the decompiler just decided to write the code this way.

Comment: @isbadawi I didn't decompile it. I decompressed the .jar.

Comment: You said you *did* decompile it in your question. You must have. rt.jar doesn't contain source code.

Comment: @EJP well, there were Javadoc comments, so...

Comment: So you didn't decompile it, which contradict what you said in your question, and you didn't get it from rt.jar, which also contradicts what you said in your question and also in a comment above. You unzipped it from src.zip or somewhere else. Perhaps you could correct your question to agree with the facts.

Comment: @EJP alright, sorry, I didn't remember :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because mag is a field, m is local variable. Access to local variable may be faster, though modern JITs can create such a substitute local variable automatically.

BTW you should have tell what the method you had in mind (I found it to be `equals()`), and cite original source (it is available) rather than decompiled one.

Comment: I suspect this is it.  The original `BigInteger` was probably written at a time when minimizing field lookups actually mattered and weren't optimized away.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - This isn't the original BigInteger.  I have a copy of an older version and it's much different.

Answer (score 1):

A bit (few lines) futher down, they use

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (xm[i] != m[i])
        return false;
```

So `m` isn't completely isolated. They certainly could've used `mag` instead, but it's just a design choice.

Comment: Hm, I didn't notice that. Why would they do that? I certainly don't see an advantage, and it would just take up more memory.

Comment: A good question- I would've at first assumed that the developer didn't want to directly deal with `mag` (perhaps something to do with it being a `final` variable) but there appears to be other parts of the code in which `mag[i]` is used. My guess is that this was created by a couple different developers- one of which wanted to avoid directly accessing `final` variables (for whatever reason), and the others did not.

Comment: I'm guessing that BigInteger has been intensely optimized, with lots of profiling.  And the specific assignments you see were necessary to "trick" javac and the JITC into "doing the right thing".

Answer (score 0):

When you call `length` (public final member variable of `Array`) via reflection  which is constant time operation. But it is not same in [C++](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/NOTES/Java_vs.html#arrays). You have to get first array size in bytes and after divide this result to size of int to get exact value(Maybe there is better way). I think developer has the same reflex from him C++ times and carried value into local variable to use several times.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it important to you?  The statement is not copying an array, just copying a reference -- a pointer.  And "m" will likely be allocated into a register, whereas the JVM standard requires that "mag" must usually be refetched from the object -- the JITC can't freely optimize away field references.